# Get the time in milliseconds, corresponding to a custom string

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an "events" array which holds "event" objects, like the following:

```
var events = [
    {
        name: 'event1',
        start: '10.30',
        end: '10.45'
    },{
        name: 'event2',
        start: '11.00',
        end: '12.00'
    }
]
```

Now, I will have a timeout function doing the following:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var currentTime = Date.now();

    // how can i transform the start and end times from the events object in milliseconds?

    var startEventOne = events[0].start // -> how can I transform the string 10.30 in milliseconds?

}, 1000);
```

**The question is, how can I get the time in milliseconds, equivalent to the input string? is it possible?**

Comment: 10.30 is like 10:30 am ?

Comment: I have edited the question, the idea is to get the time in milliseconds, corresponding to the string '10.30'

Comment: Fine then it should work, try it please and tell me if it is

Comment: Do you want relative time to 00:00, or a unix timestamp?

Comment: @Dygestor I will be comparing the time from the string with the currentTime which is a unix timestamp in milliseconds, I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej,

```
var timeArr, 
    hours,
    minutes,
    milliseconds,
    date;

timeArr = events[0].start.split('.');
hours = timeArr[0];
minutes timeArr[1];
date = new Date(0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, 0, 0);
milliseconds = date.getTime();
// This will return you the number of milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Transform your string in float :

   ```
   var value = parseFloat(your_string);
   ```
2. Get the entire :

   ```
    var entire = parseInt(value);
   ```
3. Get the decimal :

   ```
   var decimal = value - entire;
   ```
4. Convert into ms